# How to customize right click with already existing instance of a program?

Tags: c++, mfc, c++builder

I need to customize right click so that I can scan a directory with my anti-virus. I know how to do that using registry keys, but the problem is that I don't want to start a new instance of my program every time I want to scan a directory. My anti-virus needs to load some signature databases so it will take around 15 seconds for the program to load those. I need to use the instance of the program which I have already opened and is running for scanning the directory. How can I do that?

I am using C++Builder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you already know how to add the item to the right click contextual menu, I suggest implementing a client/server set of applications:

- A server that loads up when you turn your computer on and does the scanning, and
- The client that tells it what to do using IPC - inter-process communication.

You then add the client application to various contextual menus, passing it arguments that indicate what it should get the server to do depending on what you right-clicked on.

IPC is a bit of a pain in the butt, the easiest way is to use TCP/IP to and do local networking using a network library. There are many out there, however given you'll likely want to have other features such as UI elements and a tray icon, I suggest you look at Qt, namely the following components:

- [QtNetwork](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=qtnetwork&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.qt.nokia.com%2Fdoc%2Fqt-4.8%2Fqtnetwork.html&ei=-SwNT_TlHLCTiQfG7-H4BQ&usg=AFQjCNEfGR2sU2VOpvGkDnyAqWHUnCxa-g&sig2=DivBVBauap6zYsu2Nkxybg&cad=rja): For performing communication between the client and the server executable.
- [QSystemTrayIcon](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qsystemtrayicon.html): For displaying a small icon on the tray.

There are quite a few other little bits of Qt you'll no doubt encounter (like all the fabulous UI stuff), and fortunately Qt is well documented and help is always available here, and from the Qt Developer Network. You can get started with Qt by downloading and installing the SDK:

http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/

Best of luck :).

Comment: Thank you so much but I hoped I didn't have to write server-client applications. I tried using message passing techniques but since I am working in Embarcadero c++ builder, I can't use ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGES or ...

Comment: @lili lili To be honest, the server client system is the most straight forward method, and my own experience leads me to suggest Qt. Hmm, that's unfortunate, I can't really help you with C++Builder, and ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGES is MFC which I've avoided for the better part of 15 years. I'll have a dig and see if I can come up with something for you.

Comment: @lililili I might also suggest, MFC is a windows only solution:  I wouldn't rely on it you anticipate porting to other platforms in the future.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, I'll try to write my application as a server-client one.:)

Answer (score 1):

Implement a DDE server in your anti-virus, and then add a [`ddeexec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127429.aspx) subkey to your Registry key. Alternatively, add an OLE Automation object to your app that implements the `IDropTarget` interface, and then add a `DropTarget` subkey to your Registry key that specifies the object's `CLSID`.

Either way, whenever your menu item is then invoked, Windows will call into your existing app instance if it is already running, otherwise it will launch a new instance and then call into it.  Either way, Windows is handling all of that for you.  All you are doing is providing an entry point for Windows to call into.

I would suggest the `IDropTarget` method, because DDE is deprecated, and because `IDropTarget` is more flexible.  While your app is running, you could re-use the same `IDropTarget` object to handle OLE Drag&Drop operations on your app's UI window and Taskbar button, and support automated invokations of your scanner by other apps.